# QT C++ Store file from DB to my file system

Tags: c++, qt, filesystems, tableview

i need help, i have been researching and until now nothing, i'm creating a application in QT C++, to allow user to share files(.mp3, jpg and .txt), how can a get the file from tableview to store it in file system?

```
// getting file from DB
QByteArray fileByteArray = dbm.GetSharedFile(fileNameSelected);

QFileDialog dialog;
dialog.setOptions(QFileDialog::DontUseNativeDialog);  // with or without this
dialog.setFileMode(QFileDialog::AnyFile);
dialog.setAcceptMode(QFileDialog::AcceptSave);
dialog.setDirectory(".");
dialog.selectFile(fileNameSelected);   // magic happens here
int ret = dialog.exec();

if (ret == QDialog::Accepted)
{
    QFile f(dialog.directory ().absolutePath());
       f.open( QIODevice::WriteOnly );
      f.write(fileByteArray);
      ????
      ???
}
```

I can get the file from tableview, but after, i don't know how to save it using qfiledialog. best wishes

Answer (score 0):

There is static member at `QFileDialog` class:

```
QString QFileDialog::getSaveFileName(QWidget * parent = 0, const QString & caption = QString(), const QString & dir = QString(), const QString & filter = QString(), QString * selectedFilter = 0, Options options = 0)
```

After you get filename with this method you should check string for empty and then do with file like you do

Example:

```
QString fname =QFileDialog::getSaveFileName(); //you can set some params
if (!fname.isEmpty()) {
     QFile f(fname);
     if(f.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly))
         f.write(fileByteArray);
}
```

Comment: i will try it as soon i get home, and is possible to convert it in mp3, or i should save it in fileByteArray? It's because i need to download it from data base, and save it user computer, be the final product need to be in mp3, or any extension that they can listen.

Comment: Are you sure your byte array is not empty after database query?

Comment: Yes, because i'm printing the size of the byte Array after the query and is not empty.. is very strange....

Comment: @Afreeca there is no problems with you code except you have useless declaration `QFileDialog dialog;`. How do you check that file is empty? Also try to replace `f.write(fileByteArray);` with `f.write("12345");` and check if this data saved to file.

Comment: it's working if i try: f.write("12345"), so why my byteArray file doesn't save? if isn't empty?

Comment: I think it is empty.

Comment: I have been trying over and over again and until now no solution... The byte Array is not empty, so it should save it

Comment: Ok then change `QByteArray fileByteArray = dbm.GetSharedFile(fileNameSelected);` with `QByteArray fileByteArray("test");` If this one will work then problem for sure with your DB query.

Answer (score 0):

Like you can see the file byte array is not empty.... i may have done something wrong....

```
......
......
qDebug() << "row selected" << rowSelected;
qDebug() << "file name to download" << fileNameSelected;

QByteArray fileByteArray = dbm.GetSharedFile(fileNameSelected);

qDebug() << fileByteArray.size(); // Checking the file byte array size

QFileDialog dialog;


QString fname =QFileDialog::getSaveFileName(); //you can set some params
if (!fname.isEmpty()) {
     QFile f(fname);
     if(f.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly))
         f.write(fileByteArray);
}

       qDebug() << fileByteArray.size(); // file size
```

}